# Outlook.com app cannot be used with data/3G

Tags: 3g, outlook, active-sync

I have been using the the Hotmail app to check my emails. Recently I downloaded the Outlook.com app since it is advertised for better performance and I preferred it's layout over the Hotmail app.

It works fine with my home and office WiFi. But when I tried to use it with my data (3G) connection, it does not synchronize with the server. My email is on a `.com` domain I own. Also I cannot even download the attachments of the previously synced emails.

Is this a bug of the app or something is wrong with my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error with your network setting. *Nothing is wrong with your device or the app*.

1. Goto `Settings` -> `More Settings` -> `Mobile Networks`
2. Now go to `Access Point Names`
3. Click your `APN`, (e.g. O2)
4. Delete the Proxy and delete the IP Address within it, so it is "Not set"

This was solved in the [Microsoft forums.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/mail-sync/outlookcom-app-on-android-phone-will-only-work/978dd5e2-d24c-4f3b-9bdb-547f021679db?page=4&msgId=8327fc46-2715-4995-a1b6-34f96dfea5b3)

Comment: Thanks a lot boss! this is a life saver!! worked like a charm!!